# AttributeError when using theano backend with CPU

Tags: python, keras, theano, conv-neural-network

I am trying to run [this](https://github.com/imlab-uiip/keras-segnet/blob/master/SegNet.ipynb) python notebook where a well known convolutional neural network is implemented using Keras. The author uses theano as a backend and uses his cpu device. Because my CPU is not supported by CUDA (which is needed to use it) i will try to use my gpu (to begin with). 
I installed keras and theano plus the needed requirements following [this](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html) link. I skipped the gpu configuration since I want to use my GPU.

To use my GPU I changed the device flag in one of the first lines resulting in this:

```
#%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import sys

from skimage.io import imread
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import os
os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND'] = 'theano'
os.environ['THEANO_FLAGS'] = 'mode=FAST_RUN, device=cpu, floatX=float32, optimizer=fast_compile'

from keras import models
from keras.optimizers import SGD
```

This gives me an error:

```
AttributeError: ('This name is already taken', 'floatX')
```

I found solutions but primarily for GPU users. I also read [somewhere](https://github.com/leriomaggio/deep-learning-keras-tensorflow/issues/3) that I have to delete a $HOME/.theanorc file, however I cannot find this file.

Can anyone shed some light on what causes this error and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it says `"AttributeError: ('This name is already taken', 'floatX')"` 
is most likely because the `floatX` is already defined in `.theanorc.txt`  file.

You can either remove `"floatX=float32, "` from

```
os.environ['THEANO_FLAGS'] = 'mode=FAST_RUN, device=cpu, floatX=float32, optimizer=fast_compile'
```

and repeat same for similar other attributes.

Better alternative than that is: run python and type,

```
import os 
print(os.path.expanduser('~/.theanorc.txt'))
```

It will show where `.theanorc.txt` file is located in windows

Comment: There is no theanorc file in the location of  `os.path.expanduser('~/.theanorc.txt')`. I tried `file.path.exists(os.path.expanduser('~/.theanorc.txt'))`. The error is not there anymore when I remove `floatX=float32` but I receive another error now. Can it be that the absence of the file causes me trouble along the way?

Comment: No, by default, you do not have any .theanorc file (at least that's the case in linux). You create it if you want to define custom values. What error do you get now?

Comment: It's a lot later and probably unrelated then. When I load the model I get `total size of new array must be unchanged`.

Comment: Yup, sounds unrelated.